# Spring integration: unexpected behavior on error handling in splitter-aggregator flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have following failing test. The question is why reply in case of error on one of splitted "sub-messages" is error only, without result for the other, successfully-handled, sub-message (as expected in test)? Is there a modification to this code to achieve result expected in test?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ErrorHandlingTests {

    @Autowired
    StringsService stringsService;

    interface StringsService {
        @Nonnull
        List<String> process(@Nonnull List<String> data);
    }

    @EnableIntegration
    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        IntegrationFlow errorHandler() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from("errorChannel")
                    .<MessagingException>handle((ex, h) -> "Failure for " + ex.getFailedMessage().getPayload())
                    .get();
        }

        @Bean
        IntegrationFlow errorsHandlingFlow2() {
            AtomicInteger incomingCorrelationId = new AtomicInteger();

            return IntegrationFlows.from(StringsService.class, gws -> gws.errorChannel("errorChannel"))
                    .split(new AbstractMessageSplitter() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object splitMessage(Message<?> message) {
                            List<String> strings = (List<String>) message.getPayload();
                            int id = incomingCorrelationId.get();
                            return strings
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(r -> MessageBuilder
                                            .withPayload(r)
                                            .setHeader(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID, id)
                                            .setHeader(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_SIZE, strings.size())
                                            .build())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        }
                    })
                    .transform(new AbstractPayloadTransformer<String, String>() {
                        @Override
                        protected String transformPayload(String s) {
                            if (s.contains("oops"))
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad value");

                            return "R: " + s;
                        }
                    })
                    .aggregate(a -> a.outputProcessor(new AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object aggregatePayloads(MessageGroup group, Map<String, Object> defaultHeaders) {
                            return group.getMessages()
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(m -> (String) m.getPayload())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        }
                    }))
                    .get();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testErrorHandlingInFlow2() {
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("R: a", "R: b"), stringsService.process(Arrays.asList("a", "b")));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("R: a", "Failure for oops"), stringsService.process(Arrays.asList("a", "oops")));
    }
}
```

---

**Updated version**, working, with applied advice.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ErrorHandlingTests2 {

    interface StringsService {
        @Nonnull
        List<String> process(@Nonnull List<String> data);
    }

    @Autowired
    StringsService stringsService;

    @EnableIntegration
    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        IntegrationFlow errorHandler() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from("errorChannel")
                    .<MessagingException>handle((ex, h) -> "Failure for " + ex.getFailedMessage().getPayload())
                    .get();
        }

        @Bean
        IntegrationFlow errorsHandlingFlow2() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(StringsService.class, gws -> gws.errorChannel("errorChannel"))
                    .split(new AbstractMessageSplitter() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object splitMessage(Message<?> message) {
                            List<String> strings = (List<String>) message.getPayload();
                            return strings
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(r -> MessageBuilder
                                            .withPayload(r)
                                            .build())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        }
                    })
                    .transform(new AbstractPayloadTransformer<String, String>() {
                        @Override
                        protected String transformPayload(String s) {
                            if (s.contains("oops"))
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad value");

                            return "R: " + s;
                        }
                    }, c -> c.advice(advice()))
                    .aggregate(a -> a.outputProcessor(new AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object aggregatePayloads(MessageGroup group, Map<String, Object> defaultHeaders) {
                            return group.getMessages()
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(m -> (String) m.getPayload())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        }
                    }))
                    .get();
        }

        @Bean
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice() {
            ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
            advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true);
            advice.setOnFailureExpression(
                    new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(s ->
                            MessageBuilder
                                    .withPayload("Failure for " + s.getPayload())
                                    .copyHeaders(s.getHeaders()).build())
            );
            return advice;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testErrorHandlingInFlow2() {
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("R: a", "R: b"), stringsService.process(Arrays.asList("a", "b")));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("R: a", "Failure for oops", "R: b"), stringsService.process(Arrays.asList("a", "oops", "b")));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The splitter does support Java `Stream`.
2. The splitter populated those headers by default. Not sure why would one need a custom `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID`. It is like this in the splitter: `final Object correlationId = message.getHeaders().getId();`
3. You have an aggregator already after a `transform()`. So, when transform throws an exception, it is really the fact that it doesn't reach the aggregator. In fact that both just don't know about each other. This is one of those first class citizen features in Spring Integration where endpoints are loosely-couple with message channels in between. And you can just send message to the same endpoint from different places. Anyway I guess it would behave the same way even with the plain Java: you have a loop and gather data into a list in the end of the loop. Now imaging you fail on the line before the gather logic, so the exception is thrown to the called and there is indeed no any info how it was gathered afterwards.

Now about the possible fix for your expected logic. Please, take a look into an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to be applied on your transformer. So, when you got an exception, it is handled in the `failureChannel` sub-flow and  a compensation messages is returned as a regular reply to be aggregated with others. See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: Sorry to pull your leg, but I've got two issues with your link: 1. applying advice to transformer still returns single-element list with reply and 2. that reply has rather cryptic message. Moreover, sample in docs using link offered doesn't show `was bad, with reason` anywhere in its output, as seems to be intended by the code. Would you mind to provide working sample, if that's not too much to ask? Thank you!

Comment: Added version with advice applied (in the way I understood it should be ) )

Comment: With `advice.setFailureChannelName("aggregate-channel");` you send an `ErrorMessage` which cannot be correlated with what you already have in the aggregator. I would suggest to go without that `failureChannel`, but just `setOnFailureExpressionString()` and `setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true)`. So, the result of that expression evaluation is going to be returned back to the transformer with all the required correlation info in the headers.

Comment: Updated, but still the same. Am I expected to manually set correlation id somehow inside advice body?

Comment: I think you caught another bug :smile: Thank you for being so persistent! When we return result from the error flow, we don't copy request headers automatically because we lost `AbstractTransformer.transform()` context here already. So, you need to modify your `failureExpression` to something like this: `"new org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage('Failure for ' + #exception.failedMessage.payload, #exception.failedMessage.headers)"`. Yes, that's too long, so you can use a `failureChannel` and some flow on it for better readability. Or you can use `FunctionExpression<Message<?>>`

Comment: So, feel free to raise a GH issue on the matter! However we might not treat it as a bug, but rather end-user experience improvement...

Comment: Ok, I've posted working fix, for future reference. Another question: is there API for 'post-processing' arbitrary (or almost aribtrary) flows ? I may have few transformers and whatnot in my flow, and I don't want to add `c -> c.advice` to every filter point there to make it resilient in the way test expected ...

Comment: No, there is no at the moment, but you probably can take a look into a `BeanPostProcessor` to customize `AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean` for their `adviceChain`.

Comment: BTW, your splitter could be now just like this `split()` and that's it.

Comment: See the fix for the mentioned "copy headers" problem: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3478

Comment: Thank you for that!